# Targeting C++ DLL to Windows XP in Visual Studio 2013 - dwmapi.dll is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp

I have a .NET 2.0 program with native C++ DLL and on Windows 8, it run without problems. When I try to run it on Windows XP, it crash. [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tells me that DWMAPI.dll is missing because of function [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But I don't use this function at all, it is simple dll for console application. Is there any project settings i can turn this feature off?

See dependency walker result:

[image: dependency walker]

The project settings in Visual Studio:

General settings:

[image: general settings]

C++ options:
[image]

Linker settings:

[image: linker settings]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you correctly amended the default `targetver.h` to `#define` the appropriate `WINVER` etc.? [See here for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: yes, minimum required version is set 5.01, hopefully this behave like these defines.

Comment: Have you set ``_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501``? Also, ``v120_xp`` only supports Windows XP Service Pack 3, not SP2 or older.

Comment: I have add /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501  and still same problem. Interesting is if I build is as exe (not DLL), it does work. I cannot find any diference in project settings exe, dll

Comment: But I still don't undestand why it link DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea. Isn't it MFC? I don't use MFC in my project. Isn't it that problem?